# Any basis of a $C_2$ space admits a countable subcollection as a basis

Tags: general-topology

If a topological space $X$ is $C_2$, id est, $X$ admits an at most countable basis $\{B_n\}$, then if $\{V_\alpha\}$ is a basis of $X$, there exists an at most countable subcollection $\{V_n\}$ which is also a basis.

I'm asked to prove the above. But I get stuck. It should perhaps be noted that prior to the current problem, I'm asked to prove that any non-intersecting family of open sets in $X$ is at most countable (which is quite easy): this may serve as a hint, but so far I'm still at a loss how to apply it.

My initial attempt is pick $\{V_n\}$ such that  $V_n\subset B_n$, which can be done since $\{V_\alpha\}$ is a basis, but unfortunately the resulting subcollection $\{V_n\}$ may very likely fail to be a basis. For example in $\Bbb R$ under the usual topology let $B_{n,k}=B(q_n,1/k)$ in which $q_1,\cdots,q_n,\cdots$ is the enumeration of $\Bbb Q$, and let $\{V_\alpha\}$ be all open intervals, then we can pick $V_{n,k}=B(q_n, 1/10^{n+k})\subset B_{n,k}$. However the family of $V_{n,k}$ can't cover $\Bbb R$ since $\sum_{n,k}\mu(V_{n,k})$ converges. So this attempt is futile, whose problem lies in the possibility that $V_{n,k}$ turns awfully "small" in the end.

So what are other ways that can avoid such a problem, id est, make a valid construction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw your $B_n,k$ sets are also the nice answer to a interesting question: are there open sets $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. the boundary of $U$ is not a set of measure zero.

Comment: @MaikPickl I well understand this.

Comment: @MaikPickl and the real line minus the union of them also furnishes a nice example of a nowhere dense closed set with positive measure. I somewhat   suspect we are essentially talking about the same thing, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

Choose for every $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ an element $V_{m,n}\in \{V_\alpha\}$  s.t. $ B_m\subset V_{m,n} \subset B_n$ if such an element exists. The claim is that $ \{ V_{m,n}\} $ is a basis of $X$.

Proof: Let $U\subset X$ be open. Let $x \in U$ be an element. Now since $\{ B_n\}$ is basis there is a $B_n$ such that $x \in B_n$ and $B_n \subset U$. Now since $\{V_\alpha \}$ is basis, there is a $V\in \{V_\alpha \}$ with $x \in V$ and $V \subset B_n$. Again since $\{ B_n\}$ is a basis there is a element $B_m$ with $B_m\subset V \subset B_n$ and furthermore $x \in B_m$. So by definition of  $ \{ V_{m,n}\} $ there is an element $V_{m,n}$ s.t. $x \in B_m\subset V_{m,n} \subset B_n\subset U$.

Since $x \in U$ was arbitrary you can cover $U$ with elements of $ \{ V_{m,n}\} $. This shows the claim.

Comment: Nicely done. Thanks!